# how do i use a hashmap keys to an array of strings?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

im currently working on a multiple class assignment where i have to add a course based on whether the prerequisites exist within the program.
im storing my courses within the program class using a hashmap. (thought i would come in handy) however, im having a bit of trouble ensuring that these preReqs exist.
here is some code ive currently got going

```
public boolean checkForCourseFeasiblity(AbstractCourse c) throws ProgramException 
{


    AbstractCourse[] tempArray = new AbstractCourse[0];


    tempArray=    courses.keySet().toArray(tempArray);


    String[] preReqsArray = new String[1];
    preReqsArray = c.getPreReqs();
    //gets all course values and stores them in tempArray


    for(int i = 0; i < preReqsArray.length; i++)
    {

        if(courses.containsKey(preReqsArray[i])) 
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (!courses.containsKey(preReqsArray[i]))
        {
            throw new ProgramException("preReqs do not exist"); //?

        }


    }
    return true;
}
```

ok so basically, tempArray is storing all the keySets inside the courses hashmap and i need to compare all of them with the preReqs (which is an array of Strings). if the preReqs exist within the keyset then add the course, if they dont do not add the course. return true if the course adds otherwise through me an exception. keep in mind my keysets are Strings e.g. a keyset value could be "Programming1" and the required prerquisite for a course could be "programming1". if this is the case add then add the course as the prereq course exists in the keyset.
i believe my error to be when i initialize mypreReqsArray with c.getPreReqs (note: getPreReqs is a getter with a return type String[]).
it would be really great if someone could aid me with my dilemma. ive tried to provide as much as possible, i feel like ive been going around in circles for the past 3 hours :(
-Thank you.

Comment: `//gets all course values and stores them in tempArray`
What are you doing with tempArray, it appears you declare it and then don't really do anything with it?

Comment: If you initialize map and array we can trace it and see the result, i checked `if(courses.containsKey(preReqsArray[i]))` and this line is ok, please initialize them some test data to trace the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, you don't need tempArray. The "for each" loop looks lots nicer too. If you want to throw an Exception I would put that logic in the place that calls this method.

```
public boolean checkForCourseFeasiblity(AbstractCourse c)
{

  for(String each : c.getPreReqs())
  {
      if(! courses.containsKey(each)) 
      {
          return false;
      }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: hey. i understand this completelly but im still getting a null pointer error so im thinking it has something to do with my c.getPreReqs(). perhaps it thinks it is a String even though the get method is in the return type String[]

Comment: A null pointer exception might be thrown if the `AbstractCourse c` that you pass to this method is null or if `courses` is null.